# из данного списка получить массив подряд идущих простых чисел и найти их сумму, если таких массивов несколько, найти тот массив который длиннее и сумм

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список чисел который я ввожу с экрана, нужно найти наибольшее количество подряд идущих простых чисел в порядке возрастания (отрицательные тоже считаются) и найти их, если этих рядов несколько, считать тот ряд у которого сумма этих простых чисел больше.

Вот сам код

```py
from itertools import groupby

nums = map(int, input().split())


def isPrime(n):
    if n < 0:
        n = -n
    elif n == 0 or n == 1:
        return False
    for a in range(2, (n//2)+1):
        if n % a == 0:
            return False
    return True

primes = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(map(int,nums),key=isPrime) if k]

res = max(filter(lambda x: x==sorted(x),primes),key=sum,default=[])

print(len(res), sum(res))
```

Вот пример ввода и вывода:

Ввод:
`20 -7 -7 -2 0 1 3 5 5 10`

Вывод:
`3 13`

Тут посчиталось что сумма ряда `3 5 5`  больше чем `-7 -7 -2`, из за этого взяли `3 5 5`

Ещё один пример
Ввод:
`5 -2 -2 10 8`

Вывод:
`2   -4`

вроде бы на вот эти вводы код работает, но когда ввожу
`7 2 7 4 4 10 12 7 -2 -4 7`
мне почему разбивает на эти массивы:
`[7, 2, 7], [7, -2], [7]` a должен был на эти `[7], [2, 7], [7], [-2], [7]`

Смысл в том, что он ищет среди этих массивов самый длинный а потом считает их сумму, в этом случае, это массив `[2, 7]`
Не могу понять, почему иногда код работает, а иногда нет.
Может выдать мне, когда ввожу, например:
`2 2 2 2 2 7 5`
он разбивает на массив:
`[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 5]`
а не на массивы
 `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7], [5]`

Comment: я не люблю включать "зануда моде", но по определению "Просто́е число́ — натуральное (целое положительное) число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя". Это я к тому, что отрицательных простых чисел не бывает. Ну или называются они "простыми числами со знаком минус".

Comment: Я что-то не вижу нигде в коде никаких проверок на возрастание. Вот оно и группирует просто последовательности простых чисел.

Comment: можете какую то наводку дать, через что мне лучше пойти, чтобы находило простые числа по возрастанию?

Comment: Хорошая задача. Интересно было бы отыскать изящное решение. Какое-нибудь без циклов с хранимым состоянием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами указали что разбиение на группы слишком грубое. Совсем простого решения я не нашёл. Можно сделать аннотации - каждому числу из списка приписать номер группы в которое оно входит. Одновременно с аннотированием из списка удаляются не простые.

`k` - ключ/номер группы. Ключ увеличивается если очередное число не простое или простое но меньше предыдущего. Наружу выдаются пары `(ключ, число)` только для простых чисел (это не оптимизация!).

```
def group_primes(seq):
    k = 0
    prev_n = 0
    for n in seq:
        prime = is_prime(abs(n))
        if not prime or prev_n > n:
            k += 1
        if prime:
            yield k, n
        prev_n = n
```

> ```
> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 5] ->
> [(0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 7), (1, 5)]
>
> [7, 2, 7, 4, 4, 10, 12, 7, -2, -4, 7] ->
> [(0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 7), (6, 7), (7, -2), (8, 7)]
> ```

Из аннотированной последовательности `groupby` с соответствующим ключом правильно соберёт группы, которые нужно будет очистить удалив ключи и оставив числа.

```
import itertools
import math


def is_prime(n):
    assert n >= 0
    if n < 2:
        return False
    return all(n % d != 0 for d in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) + 1))


def group_primes(seq):
    k = 0
    prev_n = 0
    for n in seq:
        prime = is_prime(abs(n))
        if not prime or prev_n > n:
            k += 1
        if prime:
            yield k, n
        prev_n = n


def main():
    # все числа
    a = map(int, input().split())

    # простые числа, аннотированные ключами
    b = group_primes(a)

    # простые числа, собранные в группы
    c = (
        # из группы оставляем только числа без ключей
        tuple(n for _, n in g)
        # группировка только по ключу, значение игнорируется
        for k, g in itertools.groupby(b, key=lambda v: v[0])
    )

    # переделываем группы в пары (длинна, сумма)
    d = ((len(g), sum(g)) for g in c)

    # выбираем самую длинную группу
    # если таких несколько, то с самой большой суммой
    e = max(d, default=(0, 0))

    print(*e)


main()
```

Группа `3 5 5` обходит `-7 -7 -2`:

> ```
> $ echo "20 -7 -7 -2 0 1 3 5 5 10" | python ascending-primes.py 
> 3 13
> ```

Здесь наибольшая по сумме группа `2 7`:

> ```
> $ echo "7 2 7 4 4 10 12 7 -2 -4 7" | python ascending-primes.py
> 2 9
> ```

Переход через ноль в группе `-3 -2 2 3`:

> ```
> $ echo "-3 -2 2 3" | python ascending-primes.py 
> 4 0
> ```

Ни одного простого:

> ```
> $ echo "0 1 4 6 8 9 10 12" | python ascending-primes.py 
> 0 0
> ```

Длина группы важнее суммы (и снова переход через ноль):

> ```
> $ echo "7 2 5 5 5 15 10 -7 -7 -5 -2 -2 5" | python ascending-primes.py 
> 6 -18
> ```

Comment: спасибо большое за решение, немного изменил функцию is_prime, в моем случае отрицательное по модулю число, тоже простое. И из-за этого, он ряд из отрицательных чисел тоже считать должен, например в ситуации : Ввод: `7 2 5 5 5 15 10 -7 -7 -5 -2 -2 5` и вывод: `4 17` , а должно быть `5 -23`. И еще в таких ситуациях где вообще нет ряда из простых чисел, что выводит `0 0`, например: ввод: `0 0 1 8 4` вывод: `0 0`. В моем ситуации 1 не простое число. Из за того что изменил функцию is_prime на свой, мне выводит ошибку что max()  is an empty sequence, не могу до конца понять как работает itertools.

Comment: В коде вызывается `is_prime(abs())`. Должен получаться тот же результат что и у вас. Единица - не простое число и у меня и у вас.

Comment: Вызов `max` дополнил параметром `default=()` для обработки случая когда простых в списке нет совсем.

Comment: Про ваш пример: какую группу выбрать `4 17` или `5 -23`? В вопросе сказано "максимальная сумма" и `17 > -23`, следовательно ответ `4 17`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ещё пример из вопроса: `20 -7 -7 -2 0 1 3 5 5 10` -> `3 13` не `3 -16`.

Comment: а, извините, сам не правильно обьяснил, сперва ищет где самый большой ряд простых чисел, а потом считает их сумму, если одинаковых по числу рядов несколько, то берет тот ряд, сумма которого больше, а так спасибо, сейчас начинаю понимать что да как

Comment: Поправил код чтобы правильно учитывать длину. В примере `7 2 5 5 5 15 10 -7 -7 -5 -2 -2 5` самая длинная группа `-7 -7 -5 -2 -2 5` - шесть элементов.

Comment: благодарю за комментарии, реально, больше начинаю понимать